# Neural Network in Julia (Multilayer Perceptron)

Tags: neural-network, julia

I wrote a simple [multilayer perceptron in Julia](https://gitlab.com/andy-sb/nn), which seems to work fine on different datasets, e.g. the [MNIST dataset](https://docs.juliahub.com/MLDatasets/9CUQK/0.5.3/datasets/MNIST/) with a success rate of about 90% after a few seconds of training. But I would like constructive criticism of the program and I'm very new to the Julia programming language, so feedback on the formatting is very welcome.

This is `network.jl`:

```
# network: weighted sums, activations, weights, biases, gradient
mutable struct NN
    dims :: Vector{Int}
       z :: Vector{Vector{Float64}}
       a :: Vector{Vector{Float64}}
       w :: Vector{Matrix{Float64}}
       b :: Vector{Vector{Float64}}
      ∇a :: Vector{Vector{Float64}}
      ∇w :: Vector{Matrix{Float64}}
      ∇b :: Vector{Vector{Float64}}
     Σ∇w :: Vector{Matrix{Float64}}
     Σ∇b :: Vector{Vector{Float64}}
end

Data = Vector{Tuple{Vector{Float64}, Vector{Float64}}}

# fill vectors and matrices, needs improvement
function init(dims :: Vector{Int}) :: NN
    n = NN([], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [])
    n.dims = dims

    for i in 1:length(dims)
        push!(n.a,   Vector{Float64}(undef, dims[i]))
        push!(n.∇a,  Vector{Float64}(undef, dims[i]))
    end

    for i in 2:length(dims)
        push!(n.z,   Vector{Float64}(undef, dims[i]))

        push!(n.w,   randn(dims[i], dims[i - 1]))
        push!(n.∇w,  Matrix{Float64}(undef, dims[i], dims[i - 1]))
        push!(n.Σ∇w, Matrix{Float64}(undef, dims[i], dims[i - 1]))

        push!(n.b,   randn(dims[i]))
        push!(n.∇b,  Vector{Float64}(undef, dims[i]))
        push!(n.Σ∇b, Vector{Float64}(undef, dims[i]))
    end

    return n
end

# leaky ReLU to avoid dead neurons
ReLU(x)  = max(0.01 * x, x)
ReLU′(x) = x >= 0 ? 1 : 0.01

σ(x)  = 1 / (1 + exp(-x))
σ′(x) = σ(x) * (1 - σ(x))

const act  = σ
const act′ = σ′

function forward!(n :: NN)
    for i in 1:length(n.dims) - 1
        n.z[i] = n.w[i] * n.a[i] + n.b[i]
        n.a[i + 1] = act.(n.z[i])
    end
end

cost(output, expected) = sum((output - expected) .^ 2)

function backprop!(n :: NN, expected :: Vector{Float64})
    len = length(n.dims)

    n.∇a[len] = 2 .* (n.a[len] - expected)

    for i in len - 1:-1:1
        n.∇a[i] .= 0
        n.∇b[i] = act′.(n.z[i]) .* n.∇a[i + 1]
        for j in 1:dims[i + 1]
            if i != 1
                n.∇a[i] += n.w[i][j, :] .* n.∇b[i][j]
            end
            n.∇w[i][j, :] = n.a[i] .* n.∇b[i][j]
        end
    end
end

# data: [(input, expected)], only one batch!
function train!(n :: NN, data :: Data) :: Float64
    for i in 1:length(n.dims) - 1
        n.Σ∇w[i] .= 0
        n.Σ∇b[i] .= 0
    end

    Σcost = 0
        
    for d in data
        n.a[1] = d[1]
        forward!(n)
        Σcost += cost(n.a[length(n.dims)], d[2]) / length(data)

        backprop!(n, d[2])
        n.Σ∇w .+= n.∇w / length(data)
        n.Σ∇b .+= n.∇b / length(data)
    end

    # play around with factor
    n.w -= 5 * n.Σ∇w
    n.b -= 5 * n.Σ∇b

    return Σcost
end
```

### Example approximating sin(x)

I added the following example of approximating sin(x) using the above network to [the GitLab repository](https://gitlab.com/andy-sb/nn). You might want to reduce the number of batches, depending on your computing resources.

Here is `examples/sin.jl`:

```
using Printf

include("../network.jl")

dims = [1, 10, 10, 10, 1]
len = length(dims)

n = init(dims)

# batched training data: [[(input, expected)]]
batches = [Data(undef, 5) for i in 1:100000]
for batch in batches
    for j in eachindex(batch)
        x = rand() * pi * 2
        batch[j] = ([x], [sin(x) / 2 + 0.5])
    end
end

for batch in batches
    @printf "Σcost = %.12f\n" train!(n, batch)
end

println("\nTesting with random values:\n---------------------------")
for i in 1:10
    n.a[1][1] = rand() * pi * 2
    forward!(n)
    expected = sin(n.a[1][1]) / 2 + 0.5
    @printf "sin(%.6f) = %.6f | NN: %.6f\n" n.a[1][1] expected n.a[len][1]
end
```

I also wrote [some Pluto.jl notebooks](https://gitlab.com/andy-sb/notebooks) with a friend, that use the above neural network and train it on e.g. the MNIST dataset, if you want to have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall this looks very good. The main change I would make is putting a `@views` on `backprop!` since slicing in Julia makes a copy by default.

```
function backprop!(n :: NN, expected :: Vector{Float64})
    len = length(n.dims)

    n.∇a[len] = 2 .* (n.a[len] - expected)

    for i in len - 1:-1:1
        n.∇a[i] .= 0
        n.∇b[i] = act′.(n.z[i]) .* n.∇a[i + 1]
        @views for j in 1:dims[i + 1]
            if i != 1
                n.∇a[i] += n.w[i][j, :] .* n.∇b[i][j]
            end
            n.∇w[i][j, :] = n.a[i] .* n.∇b[i][j]
        end
    end
end
```